# Invalid date error whiie inserting int(15) column at row 154000 in "ALTER TABLE CONTROLDEHORAS ADD IDCLIENTE INT(15) NOT NULL AFTER FIN" sentence

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an upgrade on my customer's database. my customer database has up to 300000 rows.
What I am trying to to is to insert a new column called IDCLIENTE INT(15).
Don't know why when I try to do this at customer's appears an annoying error: "Invalid date value '0000-00-00' in column FECHA at row 150000"
I have a column "FECHA". But I am not touching it!

But when I try the sentence in my computer it runs ok. (30 rows)

I tried it with phpmyadmin and by code.
Couldn't find it by google because it is masked by other date errors.

### EjecutarSQL($QL);

?>
I have a function "EjecutarSQL($SQL)"; that executes the connection an so on.
I tried it on phpmyadmin with same result.
'FIN' is the last column I have.

When I execute it at home it adds the column with no errors.
When Iexecute it at customer's i find:
"Incorrect date value '0000-00-00' for column FECHA at row 145850"

Comment: What version of MySQL or MariaDB is being used? What is the result of `SELECT @@sql_mode`?

Comment: In phpinfo appears:mysqlInd 5.012-dev20150407 - Soved the problem: I replaced a variable named sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE,_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSITUTION' by sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'